# cakephp Retrieving Data

Tags: cakephp, croogo

I have classes and each class contains students.
I want to get a table contains the number of students in each class.
how does **find** in this case:

$nums = $this->Student->find('count', array(
          'group' => 'Student.Class_id'));

The result of this is not correct

Comment: any body response me

Comment: ????????????? pleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’re a few ways to archive it:

1. Use a virtual field with find-all

   ```
   $this->Student->virtualFields = array('count' => 'COUNT(Student.' . $this->Student->primaryKey .')');
   $this->Student->find("all", array('fields' => 'count', 'group' => 'Student.Class_id'));
   ```
2. Build a custom query

   ```
   $this->Student->query("SELECT COUNT(Student.{$this->Student->primaryKey}) as 'count' FROM students Student GROUP BY Student.Class_id");
   ```

Comment: how to obtain this result in the view

Comment: the result is "Array ( [0] => Array ( [Student] => Array ( [count] => 3 ) ) [1] => Array ( [Student] => Array ( [count] => 2 ) ) )"

Comment: `$nums[` <index> `]['Student']['count']`